# How to sort columns in Grid View

Tags: asp.net

I have tried this one

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvDetails" **runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True" CssClass="clGrid" PageSize="25" OnRowEditing="GvDetails_RowEditing"
     OnRowCommand="GvDetails_RowCommand"  OnPageIndexChanging="GvDetails_PageIndexChanging"
     EnableModelValidation="True"  AllowSorting="true" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="GvDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>

     <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" >
        <HeaderStyle Width="35%" CssClass="gridHeader"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="gridItem" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
      </asp:BoundField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But not working :(

Comment: Grid View dosent provide sorting by defauly it depends on the data source that you are using, look at these articles for understanding it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx http://forums.asp.net/p/956540/1177923.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your `DataSource` programactically, if you want sorting on your `GridView`.

There are controls from Telerik and DevExpress that do this for you, but you have to pay for them.

Fortunately, sorting the `DataSource` is pretty easy.

```
<asp:Button ID="btSort" runat="server">Sort Alphabetically</asp:Button>
```

Then on the click even call this Sort function

```
    public void SortAlphabetically()
    {
        List<string> names = // However you get your names

        // Sort from A-Z using Linq
        var sort = from s in names
                   orderby s
                   select s;

        // Set the DataSource and Bind the data
        GvDetails.DataSource = sort;
        GvDetails.DataBind();
    }
```